# Set state before render react

Tags: reactjs

I have the `App.js`, inside of it a component. Name it `Example`. I want to set the `Example`'s props with the `App.state`s. For an example, `Example` has the props: `name`,`id`. In the `App` i want to fetch the data i want from the server, and set it as the `App`'s states, then assign them to the `Example`'s props, before the app renders it. The problem here is that i read about `componentWillMount()`, but the React documentation says that it's not the best way. Then, what's the best way?

Comment: You need to write the code too. That will help somebody to understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General approach is to store ajax `response` inside `App` and when response has been saved into the state, render `Example` component with data fetched from response

```
class App extends React.Component
  state = { response: null }

  componentDidMount() {
    runYouFetchHere
      .then((response) => this.setState({ response }))
  }

  render() {
    const { response } = this.state

    if (response === null) { return null }

    return (
      <Example name={response.name} id={response.id} />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When there is an update in react component then any of the following update methods are called.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Trying to set the state inside

```
componentWillRecieveProps(){
    this.setState({ })
}
```

Comment: Thx, but syntax typos in your example
`componentWillReceiveProps`
instead of `componentWillRecieveProps`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info man!. But I think it is deprecated now. So, we have getDerivedStateFromProps. In place of this.